# Jquery Vegas and footer problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey all i'm having a bit of trouble with my footer and a javascript. I'm running jquery vegas background and somehow it is highjacking my footer background and making it disappear on load. If you check out the website and go to contact and reload you will see what its doing.

Pastebin links to all coding involved.

[HTML element](https://pastebin.com/XRT8S748)

[javascript pastbin](https://pastebin.com/jpw3YPu5)

[contact section css](https://pastebin.com/44Qygx8g)

[Website here](http://10davidrp.com)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please include the code in the post, not links. Thanks.

Comment: check your console errors.

Comment: question answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add to your footer a position relative

```
#contact {
    position: relative; 
}
```

Comment: you are the man, thank you very much. Not to sound annoying but might you explain to me why this fixes it. Don't have to just in terms of learning would be nice to know. :) appreciate your help.